# How to return the same element multiple times

Tags: react-native

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <Icon color='red' name='star' />
    <Icon color='red' name='star' />
    <Icon color='red' name='star' />
    <Icon color='red' name='star' />
    <Icon color='red' name='star' />
</View>
```

For the above code, instead of typing Icon five times, how to write a function to return the specific number of times.

Comment: You should search more about this subject, you can use something like [map](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, but there is probably a better way.

```
     getMyIcons = () => {
         let iconArray = []
         for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
            array.push(
                <Icon color='red' name='star' />
            )
        }
        return iconArray
    }

...

render{
    return(
        {this.getMyIcons()}
    )
}
```